# Why class member data has to be static in order to be accessed by templated struct member of templated class?

Tags: c++

The question title could *probably* be better written... but anyways:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric> //std::iota
#include <sstream>

template<std::size_t N>
class JolloManager
{
private:
    enum PlayerId { princeID = 100, princessID = 101 };
    PlayerCards<princeID,   2> prince;
    PlayerCards<princessID, 3> princess;
    std::array<int, N> deck;
private:
    template<int ID, int c> struct PlayerCards
    {
        int id {ID};
        int cards[c] {0};
        friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, PlayerCards& p) {
            for(auto& i : p.cards) {
                is >> i;
                //set deck[index] = prince or princess FLAG
                deck[i] = p.id; //error: invalid use of non-static data member 'JolloManager<N>::deck'
            }
            return is;
        }
    };
public:
    JolloManager() {
        std::iota(deck.begin()+1, deck.end(), 1);
    };
public:
    bool Read();
    int FinalCard();
};

template<std::size_t N>
bool JolloManager<N>::Read()
{
    static std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream issline(line);

    issline >> prince;
    issline >> princess;

    if(prince.cards[0] == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    JolloManager<52> JManager;
    JManager.Read();
    return 0;
}
```

Why must `deck` be static? This would defeat the use of multiple instances of the class.

Comment: Aside: why `std::iota(deck.begin()+1, deck.end(), 1)` and not `std::iota(deck.begin(), deck.end(), 0)`?

Comment: you try to access member object JolloManager::deck from other object struct PlayerCards

Comment: Aside: why `std::array<int, N> deck;` but `int cards[c] {0};`?

Comment: uh, wow. I thought of `cards` being a raw array because it would always be `2` or `3` and `deck` any possible size. time  to re-evaluate my reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all functions declared with `friend` in class definitions are not member functions of these classes. They are instead placed into the enclosing namespace.

Secondly, enclosing classes do not intrinsically contain any instance of a nested class as member, nor does an instance of the nested class have any intrinsic reference to an instance of the enclosing class.

Therefore there is no instance of `JolloManager` that `deck` could refer to if it is a non-static member.

You need to decide which instance's `deck` you mean and you need to provide that information to the operator overload, by e.g. holding a pointer/reference to the `JolloManager` instance in the `PlayerCards` instance passed to it, so that you can e.g. use `p.jollo_manager.deck` or `p.jollo_manager->deck`.

Comment: `nor does an instance of the nested class have any intrinsic reference to an instance of the enclosing class.` Wow, why would it be this way? Isn't it kinda like that a class method could not acess the class data members:?

Comment: @ViníciusMagalhãesHorta Nested classes behave mostly the same as if you declared them outside the enclosing class. The main differences are that 1. the nested class does not pollute the enclosing namespace (it is in the "namespace" of the enclosing class) and may be hidden by making it `private`,  2. the nested class can access private members of the enclosing class without needing to `friend` them (but it still needs an instance to do so and, 3. there is a nested class instantiation for every template instantiation of the enclosing class.

Comment: @ViníciusMagalhãesHorta If non of these properties are important to you, you can just as well put the nested class (template) outside the enclosing class (template).

Comment: Oh. well, the only reason why I put it inside `JolloManager` is because I thought  that since `PlayerCards` would only be used by  `JolloManager` it would make sense that it would be within it.

Comment: @ViníciusMagalhãesHorta It probably is still the correct thing to do. If you put `PlayerCards` outside `JolloManager`, then you need to give it another template parameter `std::size_t N`, because it will need a reference/pointer member of type `JolloManager<N>` (At least if you want to keep using the `operato>>` overlaod as you try to do in the question) . This then also means putting extra template arguments on any use of `PlayerCards` inside `JolloManager`. This will be more complex than just having the class templates be nested. Basically my third point applies here.